# Synchronizing data between different computers through my application

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, data-synchronization

I'm create a product management application that runs on different networked computers via a MySQL database written in C # (WPF). So I intend to keep the data of computers all synchronized in ways that if a user delete a product, it disappears on all computers, or if a change in a product is made, it is applied on all machines with open application. But I have not achieved good results, I download the data using an observable collie as a source, and whenever I want to have updated data on a machine, I have to close the window and return to reopen it, the time-consuming and hates user. Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? What should I do or study? What are the key words for me to search about and solve my problem?

Comment: Do you ever refresh the collection? Why not query the database every time the user requests to see that particular data, and if they are currently viewing it, refresh it periodically?

Comment: ServerFault.com may be better place to ask if you just need that functionality for particular platform (assuming "product" means "program/application"). If it is entertainment/education exercise - dropbox has some talks/whitepaper on file sync you can start with. "Cache synchronization" may be a search term you are looking for...

Comment: Ron, i Cant Do That, Because For It Ill Need To Regist All Users Modification And Query Everytime, Until The Item Already Updated Will Be Scaned... I Just Want To Query An Item If Is Realy Not Updated, But You Need To Know That Is a Network App And All Computers Need To Scan :'(, Alexei, Thanks

Comment: can't you just use mysql replication?

Comment: Yeap, Ill Search About It abro! Thanks :)